# Array Lists Stored In Static Variables in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse, static

I build an android application, and i stored around 5 array lists in static variables, so is this way recommended, and if its not, what is the affect of using such way on the performance of the application?

Comment: It all depends on the context.

Comment: static variables are belongs to class, not to any instances. Keep this in mind

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the context.  Let's say you have a `Library` class that contains a `List<Book>`.  You would want the `List` to be an instance variable since each library should have its own books.  If you made the `List<Book>` static each instance of library would share the same `List`, which would be incorrect since libraries can have different books.

But let's say you had a class `FootballTeam` which contains a `List<Position>`.  Since each `Football` team has the same positions this class could be shared amongst all instances of `FootballTeam` since one team's positions will not differ from anothers.

So it really depends on what is being placed within the `List`.  Are the values stored in the `List` specific to a particular instance of a class?  If so, they should not be static.  Are the values common across of instances of a particular type?  If so they could be static.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for your response
I will illustrate more what is my question
i have 5 lists returns from webservice and i need these lists with me along all activities in the application, so is it correct to make these lists static ??